# Checking if Google Analytics has (asynchronously) finished tracking my page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-analytics

How can I check to see if the Google Analytics asynchronous snippet has finished tracking the webpage before I (for example) redirect the user?

```
if(gaFinished())
{
    ....
```

what should `gaFinished()` be?

Thanks in advance.

Alternatively I wouldn't have to do any of this if I were using synchronous Google code - but is there any up-to-date synchronous script (because I can't find one). I would prefer to do this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The _gaq array is being used as a queue, i.e., once the action has been performed it's removed from the array. In addition to removing the item from the array, it looks like the entire array is deleted once all of the actions are processed. With that in mind, the following code should do what you're looking for:

```
if (typeof _gaq.length == "undefined" || _gaq.length == 0)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Okay this looks interesting...just to clarify, will this tell me if the analytics have loaded or have loaded + registered pageview (the latter is what I am after).

Comment: @James, please see my revised answer for an explanation of how this works.

Comment: The array is unlikely to be ever deleted since it can be used to push Events or e-Commerce transactions at anytime.

Comment: It changes the array into an object with a push method. So the code above will really only tell you when the tracking code has been initialized. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the (old) synchronous snippet provided and supported by google:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try{
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script>
```

This will only allow scripts to execute further down the page after it has finished its tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `window['_gat']` exist.

**EDIT**

Like Randy solution, `window['_gat']` only tell you when the tracking code has been initialized...

An other way is `_gaq._getAsyncTracker()`, that only existe after __utm.gif call.
So you can do that :

```
var gaFinished = function(){
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gaq._getAsyncTracker();
        reutrn true;
    } catch(err) {
        return false;
    }
};
```